# Rails 'grouped_options_for_select' edit not working

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, ancestry

My model

```
Class Person
   belongs_to :job, class: "Job"
end

 Class Job
    has_ancestry orphan_strategy: :adopt
end
```

in my view

```
= form.select(:job_id, Job.all.map { |job| [job.name.titleize, job.id] }, {prompt: 'Job'}, {:class => 'form-control'})
```

when I use without grouped_options_for_select its working fine. I get the data when updating the record. but my select option is not listing properly

```
= form.select :job_id, grouped_options_for_select(Job.roots.map { |parent| [parent.name, parent.children.map { |c| [c.name, c.id]}] }), {prompt: 'Select'}, {class: "form-control"}
```

but when I use this 'grouped_options_for_select' when updating the record. the job id not appearing in my select option

```
 output 
     Parent1
         child1 <----this is in the select option
         child2 <----this is in the select option
     Parent2
        child1 <----this is in the select option
        child2 <----this is in the select option
```

for example, I have to edit the record of a job with Parent2<<Child2.

when I load the Job record my select is not getting the right record.

the select box always get the first select option

Comment: what's the output of `Job.roots.map { |parent| [parent.name, parent.children.map { |c| [c.name, c.id]}] }` ?

Comment: @Luskmo thanks for the comment the output is like the children is under the parent name.

Comment: @Luskmo i update my question

Comment: Does `Job.roots.map { |parent| [parent.name, parent.children.map { |c| [c.name, c.id]}] }` follow one of the two possible notations ? https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/grouped_options_for_select

Comment: @Luskmo the grouped_options_for_select rendering right in my HTML but his not getting my right record when I need to update

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your model. is it right?

`Job.roots.map { |parent| [parent.name, parent.children.map { |c| [c.name, c.id]}] }`

to

```
[
    ["Teacher", [["Physics", 2], ["Math", 3]]], 
    ["programmer", [["junior", 5], ["senior", 6]]]
]
```

But I think Person is not necessary for select's options.

It is snippet  for form with select box.

```
<%= form_for :form do |f| %>
  <%= f.select(
      "job_id",
      grouped_options_for_select(
        Job.roots.map { |parent| [
          parent.name,
          parent.children.map { |child| [child.id, child.name] }
        ] }
      ),
      {prompt: "Select"},
      {class: "form-control"}
      )
  %>
<% end %>
```

And it is select you want, right?

```
<select name="form[job_id]" id="form_job_id">
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <optgroup label="Teacher">
        <option value="2">Physics</option>
        <option value="3">Math</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="programmer">
        <option value="5">junior</option>
        <option value="6">senior</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

---

updated answer

when you first select 'Physics' option

```
  grouped_options_for_select(
    Job.roots.map { |parent| [
      parent.name,
      parent.children.map { |child| [child.id, child.name] }
    ] },
    2  <-- add selected_params value by N
  )
```

Comment: hi thanks for answering my question let me try your code and I will come back to you

Comment: I'm sorry for my wrong grammar when I'm trying to update the select field the record not appear in my select box

Comment: the grouped_options_for_select rendering right in my HTML but his not getting my right record when I need to update

Comment: i tried using selected: it works well but im getting error in my new _form

Comment: please update your answer with selected params. so I can accept it

Comment: What is your form error? could you print a log? Your model and code snippet aren't wrong as syntax. I think the problem come from data record or form code which you aren't add your question.

Comment: And please explain in detail how to update your Job model's records.

Comment: the error is when i render the Job record. in select box the data is not appear. but when use selected params like this grouped_options_for_select(Job.roots.map { |parent| [parent.name, parent.children.map { |c| [c.name, c.id]}] }, selected: @job.id) is now working

Comment: i just want to update your question with selected params so i can accept your question :)

Comment: Is it not working adding child.id in second param of grouped_options_for_select? If you add 3 then it is selcted Math option in my example.

Comment: im sorry im using  grouped_options_for_select(Job.roots.map { |parent| [parent.name, parent.children.map { |c| [c.name, c.id]}] }, selected: @job). in my controller @job check if there is value.

Comment: If so, is the problem completely solved? I will update my answer for others facing the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Ref [grouped_options_for_select](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/grouped_options_for_select)

- Without grouped_options_for_select

Here you are using `Job.all` you are showing all the jobs i.e. `parents` & `childern`.

- With grouped_options_for_select

Here you are using `Job.roots` & then `parent.children` basically you are showing only `childern.

In order to display both `parent` & `children` with proper listing you have to add parents array in `grouped_options_for_select` second parameter.

```
= form.select :job_id, 
  grouped_options_for_select(
    Job.roots.map { |parent| 
      [
        parent.name, 
        [parent.name, parent.id] + parent.children.map { |c| [c.name, c.id]}
       ] 
     }
   ), 
   {prompt: 'Select'}, 
   {class: "form-control"}
```

Note :- Notice `[parent.name, parent.id] +` .